# Prompting for download

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, download

Whats the best method to prompt a user to download something?  In the past I've used `window.open('file.pdf');` but I can see popup blockers having a problem with this.  Of course I'll include a manual link aswel.

I basically want something like the [Microsoft Download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=341c2ad5-8c3d-4347-8c03-08cdecd8852b).  So whats the script that prompts this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect using javascript.

```
function redirect() {
window.location = 'http://www.url.to/your.file';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"
```

To do this you may want to pass your file.pdf through a server script that forces that header on it.

What you see on that download page is just a location change. And if that page returns the download header the browser won't change page.

Answer (score 0):

Set a content disposition header with an attachment value

Comment: Done, but that wasn't my question